# How to properly subtract from a database using php and php variables?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a shopping cart and take the quantities in the cart to subtract from my inventory in my table in mysql.  But everytime i try and update it keeps on subtracting the wrong amount.  So far i have this.

```
                <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
            <center><B>Invoice</B></center>
           <?php

require 'connect.php';
require 'item.php';
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
 $result = mysqli_query($con, 'select * from products where 
id='.$_GET['id']);
 $products = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
 $item = new Item();
 $item->id = $products->id;
 $item->name = $products->name;
 $item->price = $products->price;
 $item->quantity = 1;
 // Check if the products exists in the cart
 $index = -1;
 $cart = unserialize(serialize($_SESSION['cart']));
for($i=0; $i<count($cart); $i++)
 if($cart[$i]->id==$_GET['id'])
{
 $index = $i;
 break;
}
if($index==-1)
 $_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
 else{
     $cart[$index]->quantity++;
     $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
     }
     }

// Delete products in cart
if(isset($_GET['index'])){
$cart = unserialize(serialize($_SESSION['cart']));
unset($cart[$_GET['index']]);
$cart = array_values($cart);
 $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
}
?>
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
 <tr>
   <th>Id</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Price</th>
   <th>Quantity</th>
  <th>Sub-Total</th>
 </tr>
 <?php
 $cart = unserialize(serialize($_SESSION['cart']));
 $s = 0;
 $index = 0;
 for($i=0; $i<count($cart); $i++){
 ?>
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->id; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->name; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->price; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->quantity; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $cart[$i]->price * $cart[$i]->quantity; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php 
   $index++;
   $quantitycart=$cart[$i]->quantity;
   $idcart=$cart[$i]->id;
} 
 ?>
   <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="5"</tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </table><br>
<?php
if(array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))
 {  $results = mysqli_query($con, 'select * from products'); 
for($i=0; $i<count($cart); $i++)
{
while($products= mysqli_fetch_object($results)){
$quantity= $products->quantity;

$newquantity= $quantity-$quantitycart;

$sql = "UPDATE products SET quantity='$newquantity' WHERE id='$idcart'";
}}
 if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "Record updated successfully";
  } else {
  echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
 }

 $con->close();

 }
```

$con is my connnection.  Any help would be appreciated.  The main problem is located in the last part of the code.

Comment: I bet your main problem in the future will be `select * from products where 
id='.$_GET['id']`

Comment: Your code confused me. Quantity of the product must be reduced at the time of order placement, not at shopping cart. In shopping cart, you will only compare the quantity that user desires with actual quantity of the product.

Comment: All I see is that if you have ordered a Qty of 1, it subtracts 1 from everything.  That's not good code as Kostas said

Comment: The proper way to subtract is in your database query `UPDATE table SET amount = amount - 1 WHERE id = 500;`

Comment: The best practice is to create one temp table from where you will keep comparing quantity even at the time of order placement. After order placement, ordered products going to remove from temp table and will be added in orders tables and their quantity will also be reduced from products table.